# Array formula that applies math string operators towards an array of numbers

Tags: google-sheets

Need an array formula that incorporates the string math operators inside column D and applies them to the numbers inside column C. Write your formula in column H.

[Link to sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9vBShVK_iyxOelo1Dc0THVRJtP3U0pmiPcxbrLLSJ0/edit#gid=808040802)

[image]

What I researched and [tried:](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13826624/evaluate-string-as-formula?hl=en)

```
=INDEX(QUERY(,"select "&A1),2)
```

However, the above is a single-cell formula and not an array formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `MAP()` formula to make it dynamic spill array.

```
=MAP(C5:C,D5:D,LAMBDA(c,d,IF(c="","",CHOOSEROWS(QUERY(,"select "&C&D,0),2))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works! Thank you!